# Bathroom 3 in 1 switches in seperate locations

Tags: wiring, bathroom, light, heater, exhaust

Intent: To have heater/exhaust/light unit installed with the light switch separate from the heater/exhaust.

Why? I have a light/exhaust on one switch (next to door), but would like a 3 in 1. The current wiring is in solid cement, so can't be changed. Some new wire can be run through conduit from an existing power outlet, but this outlet is in a corner, making fumbling for a light switch very tricky.

A second light has been suggested, but it sounds very inelegant.

I imagine this would require the unit to be rewired?

More Edit:
Here is the picture of the fusebox/switchboard (I hope this is what ThreePhaseEel meant...)
[image]
The light circuit seems to be 8 amps across the apartment, and then 16 amps for each room with wall outlets, and another 16amps for the stove, although one of the fuses is labelled 32 amps...?

The current light switch
[image]

A switch that would be used.
[image]

[image: where the old one was]
This is the hole from the current one - you can see a power point there - it plugged in just like a toaster.

I don't have the intended unit at hand ([IXL tastic Prime](https://www.ixlappliances.com.au/tastic-prime-3-in-1-heater-fan-light.html), or something similar), and have struggled to find pictures of the inside, but have found a wiring schematic:-
[image: wiring schematic for IXL Tastic Prime]
EDIT:
Yes, yes this is going to have to involve conduit - I'm more interested in the rewiring of the unit itself - which after looking around may involve opening up the unit, and using some 12/2 to one wall with two switches and 12/1 to the other.

The light wire (12/1) would go to the the ceiling which has an apartment wide lighting circuit, and the heater would run of the room specific circuit

Even just writing this question is helping me figure things out - much thanks. No, I'm not a sparky, but the ones I'm speaking with aren't suggesting rewiring a unit.

Comment: 1 - Pictures of the existing switch box(es) would help. 2 - What else, if anything, is on the circuit? Light & fan can legally share with bathroom receptacles or with other lights elsewhere. But a heater will basically use an entire circuit's worth of power all by itself, so really heat/light/fan should be on a circuit of its own.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please? "Wiring is in solid cement" sounds like a conduit job to me...

Comment: An overall picture of the situation, including the wall where the current switch (no pun intended) is and where the new switch(es) will be, would help as well.

Comment: Usually when a wall is concrete, they use some sort of conduit so that the individual wires can be exchanged.  If you've worked all your life in cables and/or all the youtube videos you saw assumed Romex cable, this may not be obvious.   If they are *other than* the usual black-white-red, or if there is writing on the side of the wires, this is certain.

Comment: Can you *please* get us photos of the innards of the existing boxes in question?

Comment: Can you get us photos of the insides of the switch boxes?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - I'm so so sorry, I hope that what you mean by switch box is what I think you mean by switch box. I still have a fuse board that will need to be changed out according to current local law.

Comment: @assemblism -- I'm talking about the boxes that house the lightswitches/3-in-1-switches, not the fuseboard

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, you are super duper patient.

Comment: @assemblism -- can you post a photo looking into the back of the box that houses the lightswitch please?